# API Gateway Lambda with Express, CORS are enabled but not received from Chrome

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, cors, aws-api-gateway

I've been developing a simple backend using SAM ( https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/sam/ ) NodeJS and Express.

I'm deploying the stack using the `sam cli` with its template ( based on CloudFormation ).
I've been experiencing a lot of trouble handling CORS problems.
I've been looking for an answer for a couple of days and I've tried many solutions, unsuccessfully.

Part of the `template.yml`, where I define the `AWS::Serverless::Api`:

```
Properties:
  Name: !Sub ${stackName}
  StageName: Web
  Cors:
    AllowHeaders: "'*'"
    AllowOrigin: "'*'"
    AllowMethods: "'*'"
```

inside the `app.js`I have defined also the line

`app.use(cors());`

I'm using the package `const awsServerlessExpress = require('@vendia/serverless-express')`.

Clearly, when I test every single API through Postman or cURL it works correctly, when I do the same test on Chrome ( localhost or deployed with some different hosts ) I get the classic CORS error: `... has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

AWS put a guide for troubleshooting CORS problems, and here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-test-cors.html show to test with cURL.

I do the same test with cUrl like this:

```
curl -v -X OPTIONS https://<endpoint>/auth/login -H "x-api-key: <API_KEY>" -H "Origin: https://127.0.0.1:3000" \
-H 'Access-Control-Request-Method: POST' \
-H 'Access-Control-Request-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization
```

and as I can see I receive the CORS headers correctly:

[image: Screen of cURL result]

I still don't understand why I have the CORS error in Chrome.

**UPDATE:**
I've tried the same cURL request omitting the `x-api-key` header.

The response is:
[image]

with `{"message":"Forbidden"}* Closing connection 0`

I've noticed that the OPTIONS request has the field API Key required set to true. I've tried to set it to `false`
but the curl result is the same.

Comment: Remove the `-H "x-api-key: <API_KEY>"` from the OPTIONS request you’re testing in curl. That’s because the browser doesn’t include that x-api-key header in the preflight OPTIONS call — nor will it include any other headers you might be setting in your frontend JavaScript code. Therefore, the server that request is being sent to must be configured to allow completely unauthenticated OPTIONS requests — from any origins you want to allow — and must respond to those OPTIONS requests with a 200 OK success response. Unauthenticated OPTIONS requests are a fundamental requirement of the CORS protocol.

Comment: @sideshowbarker I've tried the curl request without the x-api-key request. The API Gateway doesn't send access-control-* headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the issue!
I had set the ApiKey requirements for all the API Events.

Since the OPTIONS request don't send any authentication header, the API Gateway refuses the request so the client won't ever see the correct OPTIONS response.
I think that's a bug with SAM template/Cloudformation